# Finish activity which we started from Broadcast Receiver using context

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I started an activity with dialog theme from onReceive() method by using context variable. The started activity is having alert dialog layout with Ok and Cancel buttons. When user taps on Ok/Cancel button I am calling finish() method so the activity getting destroyed. But when I launch the application this activity is coming again. Is this because of starting the activity with context variable. Even if I set FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK also it is coming again and again when i launch the application. Can someone please help me how can I avoid this activity.

**EDIT**

```
public class C2DMMessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

     @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           if ("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE".equals(intent.getAction())) {
                  Intent customDialogIntent = new Intent(context,DialogActivity.class);
                  customDialogIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                  context.startActivity(customDialogIntent);  
           }
    }

}


public class DialogActivity extends Activity{

        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.alert_dialog);
             TextView textAlertTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textAlertTitle);
             TextView textAlertMessage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textAlertMessage);
             Button button1Alert = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1Alert);
             Button button2Alert = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2Alert);

             textAlertTitle.setText("Notification");
             textAlertMessage.setText("One notification is waiting for you. Do you want to see the notification?");

              button1AlertOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                       Intent intent = new Intent(DialogActivity.this,HomeActivity.class)
                       intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                       startActivity();
                  }
              });

    button2AlertCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                       finish();
                   }
            });
        }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.sample.ww.activity" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.5">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<permission android:name="com.sample.ww.activity.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.sample.ww.activity.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <activity android:name="SplashActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="HomeActivity"></activity>
  <activity android:theme="@style/AlertDialog.NoTitleBar" 
          android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
          android:name="DialogActivity"
          android:launchMode="singleInstance"
          android:taskAffinity="com.sample.ww.activity">
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="com.nielsen.ww.receiver.C2DMMessageReceiver"
              android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
                <category android:name="com.sample.ww.activity" />
              </intent-filter>
              <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                  <category android:name="com.sample.ww.activity" />
              </intent-filter>
     </receiver>
```

Comment: How did you registered your BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: Post your manifest and explain which Activity is which.

Comment: Is the `Intent` that the `BroadcastReceiver` is listening for being sent as 'sticky'?

Comment: I have edited my questions, can u please look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use `launchMode="singleInstance"`. You don't need that.
2. When the user taps "OK" on your DialogActivity, you start the HomeActivity but you **do not finish DialogActivity**. That's why, when you return to the application, you still see the DialogActivity. You need to call `finish()` after you call `startActivity()` in your `onClick()` method.
3. You've got the `taskAffinity` set to "com.sample.ww.activity" for all of your activities (even if you don't explicitly specify it, it defaults to the name of your package which is "com.sample.ww.activity"). If you want to have the activities run in different tasks then they need to have different taskAffinities. In any case, you may not need to have the activities running in different tasks if you fix the `finish()` problem in #2.

Comment: Thanks @David, i forgot to add that finish(), actually there is problem with Android itself. After getting push notification if I launch my application from application launcher screen I am not getting this alert dialog activity, suppose if I launch the application from Recent Apps screen then I am getting this alert dialog activity and not allowing me to enter into the application.

Comment: Can you explain what it is you are trying to accomplish? What should the behaviour be? It seems to me that you are making it far more complicated than it needs to be. Please update your question and explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sure David, Whenever I got a push notification from server I have to check whether the user is currently using the app or not. If the user is not using the app(means app got closed or in background) then I have to show an alert dialog with 'Ok' and 'View' buttons,we are calling this as out-of-app notification, if the user is using the app(user is within the app) then I have to show only 'Ok' button, we are calling this as in-app notification. When the user taps on 'Ok' button I simply closes the dialog(calling finish() method) and taps on 'View' launching my application's startup activity.

Comment: cont...

I dont have any problem with in-app-notification. Problem is with out-of-app notification,
case-1: App got closed(by tapping on Back key), we got a push notification and user taps on either 'Ok' or 'View' button, the corresponding action got performed after that if we launch the application from Recent Apps screen(which we will get when we long press on Home key) then the same alert dialog is coming again and again whenever we launch the app, even without getting any push notification, but it wont come once if we launch the app from launcher screen.

Comment: cont...<br> case-2: App is in background(By tapping on Home key), we got a push notification, whenever I am launching the DialogActivity with NEW_TASK, the application is coming to the foreground with this alert dialog but we are not expecting this. 
I hope now you got a clear picture.

Comment: The problem is with launchMode="singleInstance". You need to remove that. This creates more problems than it solves. Let me know if that fixes your problem.

Comment: I removed it previously, now it is not there.     <activity android:theme="@style/AlertDialog.NoTitleBar"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="DialogActivity">
  </activity>   This is my activity declaration in manifest.

Comment: Try the following: add android:taskAffinity="" and android:excludeFromRecents="true" to the DialogActivity. Make sure that the DialogActivity starts the main application using "Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK". You may also need to add android:noHistory="true" to the DialogActivity, but try first without it. Setting the taskAffinity to empty string disassociated the DialogActivity from the res of the activities so that they will end up in different tasks and the application should not automatically come to the foreground when the dialog appears.

Comment: @David..you are genius..it is working as I am expecting. I used only taskAffinity and excludeFromRecents as you said, i didnt use noHistory. Thanks a tonn.